# Unable to unmarshall the CXF web service object to XML

Tags: web-services, jaxb, apache-camel, jbossfuse, fuseesb

I'm trying to call a web service exposed by third party. After receiving the response I'm wrapping the response to the appropriate class. While marshalling the object of the wrapper class to xml string using "jaxb" I'm getting the error as:

> org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException: No type converter
>   available to convert from type:
>   com.unifyv4.ws.CreateOrganisationResponse to the required type:
>   java.io.InputStream with value
>   com.unifyv4.ws.CreateOrganisationResponse@312ea56e
>
> Detailed Stack Trace:
>
> n  |     BodyType           com.unifyv4.ws.CreateOrganisationResponse
>   n  |     Body
>     com.unifyv4.ws.CreateOrganisationResponse@2c9a5080
>
> ### n  | ]n  | n  | Stacktracen  |
>
> java.io.IOException:
>   org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException: No type converter
>   available to convert from type:
>   com.unifyv4.ws.CreateOrganisationResponse to the required type:
>   java.io.InputStream with value
>   com.unifyv4.ws.CreateOrganisationResponse@2c9a5080
>
> ```
> at org.apache.camel.converter.jaxb.JaxbDataFormat.marshal(JaxbDataFormat.java:141)[235:org.apache.camel.camel-jaxb:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
>
> at org.apache.camel.processor.MarshalProcessor.process(MarshalProcessor.java:83)[198:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
>
> at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)[198:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
>
> at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:448)[198:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
>
> at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)[198:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
>
> at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:121)[198:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
>
> at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.access$100(Pipeline.java:44)[198:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
>
> at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline$1.done(Pipeline.java:139)[198:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
>
> at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor$InternalCallback.done(CamelInternalProcessor.java:251)[198:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
>
> at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler$1.done(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:460)[198:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
>
> at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor$1.done(InstrumentationProcessor.java:86)[198:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
>
> at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor$1.done(SendProcessor.java:149)[198:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
>
> at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfClientCallback.handleResponse(CxfClientCallback.java:61)[207:org.apache.camel.camel-cxf:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
>
> at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:823)[74:org.apache.cxf.cxf-core:3.0.4.redhat-621084]
>
> at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1644)[96:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:3.0.4.redhat-621084]
>
> at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream$1.run(HTTPConduit.java:1155)[96:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:3.0.4.redhat-621084]
>
> at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.AutomaticWorkQueueImpl$3.run(AutomaticWorkQueueImpl.java:428)[74:org.apache.cxf.cxf-core:3.0.4.redhat-621084]
>
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)[:1.8.0_40]
>
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)[:1.8.0_40]
>
> at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.AutomaticWorkQueueImpl$AWQThreadFactory$1.run(AutomaticWorkQueueImpl.java:353)[74:org.apache.cxf.cxf-core:3.0.4.redhat-621084]
>
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.8.0_40]
> ```
>
> Caused by: org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException: No
>   type converter available to convert from type:
>   com.unifyv4.ws.CreateOrganisationResponse to the required type:
>   java.io.InputStream with value
>   com.unifyv4.ws.CreateOrganisationResponse@2c9a5080
>
> ```
> at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.BaseTypeConverterRegistry.mandatoryConvertTo(BaseTypeConverterRegistry.java:177)[198:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
>
> at org.apache.camel.core.osgi.OsgiTypeConverter.mandatoryConvertTo(OsgiTypeConverter.java:122)[204:org.apache.camel.camel-blueprint:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
>
> at org.apache.camel.converter.jaxb.JaxbDataFormat.marshal(JaxbDataFormat.java:172)[235:org.apache.camel.camel-jaxb:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
>
> at org.apache.camel.converter.jaxb.JaxbDataFormat.marshal(JaxbDataFormat.java:138)[235:org.apache.camel.camel-jaxb:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
>
> ... 20 more
> ```

Below is the blueprint.xml file and class where I'm trying to marshal the response object.

Blueprint.xml

```
<cxf:rsServer id="crmRequest" address="http://localhost:9002/rest/" serviceClass="com.spectranet.createEnterpriseCustomer.ReceiveEnterpriseRequest" />

<bean id="crmRequestBean" class="com.spectranet.createEnterpriseCustomer.ReceiveEnterpriseRequest" />

<bean id="myProcessor" class="com.spectranet.createEnterpriseCustomer.MyProcessor" />
<bean id="myProcessor2" class="com.spectranet.createEnterpriseCustomer.MyProcessor2" />

<bean id="dozerConverterLoader" class="org.apache.camel.converter.dozer.DozerTypeConverterLoader">
    <argument index="0" ref="myCamel" />
    <argument index="1" ref="createOrg" />
</bean>
<bean id="createOrg" class="org.apache.camel.converter.dozer.DozerBeanMapperConfiguration">
    <property name="mappingFiles">
        <list>
            <value>transformation.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="unifyCreateOrg" address="http://203.122.58.158:9080/unifyejb/CRMAPI" serviceClass="com.unifyv4.ws.CRMAPI" serviceName="com.unifyv4.ws.CRMAPIService" wsdlURL="wsdl/CRMAPI_WSDL.wsdl" />

<camelContext id="myCamel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
    <endpoint uri="dozer:createOrg?sourceModel=com.spectranet.createEnterpriseCustomer.CRMCAFRequest&amp;targetModel=com.unifyv4.ws.CreateOrganisation&amp;mappingFile=transformation.xml" id="crmToUnify"/>
    <dataFormats>
        <jaxb contextPath="generated" id="generated"/>
        <jaxb contextPath="com.unifyv4.ws" prettyPrint="true" encoding="UTF-8" partClass="com.unifyv4.ws.CreateOrganisationResponse" id="myPartialJaxb"/>
    </dataFormats>
    <route>
        <from uri="cxfrs:bean:crmRequest" id="crmRequest">
            <description/>
        </from>
        <convertBodyTo type="com.spectranet.createEnterpriseCustomer.CRMCAFRequest"/>
        <to pattern="InOut" ref="crmToUnify"/>
        <setHeader headerName="Username">
            <constant>admin</constant>
        </setHeader>
        <setHeader headerName="Password">
            <constant>admin</constant>
        </setHeader>
        <setHeader headerName="operationName">
            <constant>createOrganisation</constant>
        </setHeader>
        <setHeader headerName="operationNameSpace">
            <constant>http://ws.unifyv4.com/</constant>
        </setHeader>
        <log message="customer: ${in.body.organisation.customer}"/>
        <log message="ipAddress: ${in.body.sessionObject.ipAddress}"/>
        <process ref="myProcessor"/>
        <to pattern="InOut" uri="cxf:bean:unifyCreateOrg"/>
        <marshal ref="myPartialJaxb"/>
        <log message="Messsage from soap call is : ${body}"/>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

Java Code to Marshal the object to xml.

```
package com.spectranet.createEnterpriseCustomer;

import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.Processor;

import com.unifyv4.ws.CreateOrganisationResponse;
import com.unifyv4.ws.Organisation;

public class MyProcessor2 implements Processor {

    public void process(Exchange exchng) throws Exception {
        CreateOrganisationResponse orgResponse = new CreateOrganisationResponse();
        orgResponse.setReturn(exchng.getIn().getBody(Organisation.class));

        System.out.println("Organisation Created : " + orgResponse.getReturn().getOrgNo());
        exchng.getIn().setBody(orgResponse);
    }
}
```

Kindly please provide any suggestions if any.

Comment: Can you check what is the type of the body just before your marshal step.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, may I know why you want to marshal ?

Looking at route, I dont think you need to marshal any payload.

Just play around XPATH, XSLT & Camel. Camel becomes more complicated in-fact, if you want to marshal and unmarshal. I am not saying its wrong, I am saying its easier without the hassle of marshal, unmarshal, etc. Because ultimately thats what all frameworks do internally. :)

Eg: https://github.com/gnanagurus/camel-guru-projects/tree/master/camel-cxf-geocoder-example

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This issue can come when the generated class does not contain XML root element tag. Because of it, framework can not explicitly convert the objects to XML and vice versa.

Hence you are creating the response via processor, please refer your WSDL and create the wrapper response as well.

Thanks
Shiv